# Disable Apptentive logging in Android

Tags: android, apptentive

How can I disable Apptentive's torrential logging in the Android logs?

It logs very heavily - to the point of making it hard to see logs from anything else. Is there a way to control its logging level? Typically these values are: verbose, debug, error, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better [answer](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android/issues/94) now:

> Hi Den,
>
> We actually recently added this ability.

Direct link to SDK debug level setup:
http://www.apptentive.com/docs/android/integration/#logging